# Large packet loss when not ARP-Pinging

Tags: networking

I'm encountering an issue I'm unable to resolve. For starters, below is my network.

The router is connected to a VLAN access port (VLAN 123) and passes through some switches. The devices are also connected in the same manner.

```
                   ┌──────────────────┐
                   │      Switch      │                     ┌────────────────┐
┌─────────────┐    │                  │  ┌───────────────┐  │    Switch      │
│Public Router├─┐  │Access Ports      │  │2 More Switches│  │                │
└─────────────┘ └──►PVID 123     Trunk├─►│Tagged VLAN 123├─►│                │    ┌───┐
                   │                  │  └───────────────┘  │   Untagged Port├───►│RPi│
   ┌───────────┐ ┌─►PVID 456          │                     │      PVID 123  │    └───┘
   │Home Router├─┘ └──────────────────┘                     └──────────────┬─┘
   └───────────┘                                                           │      ┌─────────────────┐
                                                                           └─────►│OPi/Other Devices│
                                                                                  └─────────────────┘
```

When the Pi initially connects, I can ping it from the router and other devices just fine. However, after around 15 seconds or so, it loses connectivity.

I can restore connectivity if I continuously do an ARP-Ping from the router (specifying the Pi's MAC address), but when I stop it drops again after a few seconds.

The other devices on this network do not experience the same issue.

So far, I have tried:

- Making 100% certain this is not a physical (cable/power/grounding) issue
- Using different Pis (I have tried Pi 3B+, Pi 4B, and Pi 5)
- Using the current (Bookworm) and Legacy (Buster) Raspbian
- Checking if this is an ARP conflict - it's not
- Adjusting ARP timeouts and limits on the full network path
- Make sure nothing in the network is resource exhausted/limited (I am using a MikroTik CCR2116 as the router and MikroTik CRS-series switches)

A curveball in this is this also only happens on the "public" VLAN with over 1k+ devices (172.16.0.0/21). When I switch the VLAN to my home network with ~100 devices (192.168.1.0/24) this issue doesn't happen.

What other things can I try to resolve this issue? It seems to be a Raspberry Pi thing.